# Java SOCKS 5 Proxy authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, socks

I have a Java application JRTMT that I need to run in Windows over SOCKS5 proxy with authentication (username and password). The code of the application cannot be changed. The only option is to play with some parameters / environmental variables etc.

I have done some research and found following parameters:

> java -DsocksProxyHost=1.1.1.1 -DsocksProxyPort=1080
>   -Djava.net.socks.username=JohnDoe -Djava.net.socks.password=XXXXXXX -jar JRtmt.jar

This allows to establish the communication with SOCKS 5 Proxy. I can see SOCKS packet in Wireshark flowing both ways to and from 1.1.1.1 over port 1080. The authentication however fails. I can seen in the SOCKS protocol (in packet capture) that the application is trying to authenticate with proxy using:
 `username:winuser` (windows username) with blank password
instead of
 `username=JohnDoe` and `password=XXXXXX`

Are there any options / parameters to enforce the authentication method in Java to use username/password?

Comment: What is the issue are you facing? What is the error for the failure?

Comment: Authentication failed, since wrong credentials are being sent towards proxy.

Comment: In your packet capture, in the initial SOCKS handshake, what authentication(s) is the app offering to the proxy, and which one is the proxy choosing, before the actual authentication takes place? Sounds like Type 2 (username/password) is not being offered or chosen. It is not a secure authentication, so f other, more secure, authentications are offered, the proxy might chose one of them instead. For instance, NTLM/SSPI authentication is commonly used with a user token associated with the calling thread, not a username/password.